# Proper xpath specification between two children within the same parent?

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, firebug

So, on a given website: [for example](http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/z?c107%3aH.R.8%3a) there is a div element. I want to properly specify the xpath for a given sub-set of the main content of the page, found in:

```
<div[@id="content"> otherwise known as <div[3]>
```

Specifically, I want the xpath for the content between the second horizontal-rule (hr) tag and the third horizontal-rule (hr) tag. Which I believe should be, respectively:

```
'//div[@id="content"]/hr[2]' **AND** '//div[@id="content"]/hr'
```

I have been reading the [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) and trying to figure out if the two hr tags are siblings or not, which I believe they are. However, Python does not seem to be recognizing them as such. I have tried every derivation of:

```
"following-sibling" and "preceding:: and not(preceding::)"
```

to the point that I no longer know which is which, and what is what. I do know that I am confused, and I believe the script is being confounded by the fact that the second hr of interest is not being numbered/identified as the third hr within the content/div (does not follow logically in numbering) as it 'should' be... according to what **Firebug** has been telling me.

The bottom line is: ***How do I properly specify this xpath?*** Again, these horizontal-rule tags appear to be siblings to me so I would think it would follow a structure such as following-sibling & preceding-sibling to specify the content between these two tags.

Comment: I'm not getting any text containing "otherwise" in your document. If the content is only available after login, you might want to build an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Anyway your HTML/XML and XPath syntax is horribly messed up, you should at least be able to provide snippets with correct syntax when trying to solve more complex problems.

Comment: Copied directly from **Firebug**: //*[@id="content"]

So the location of the actual content of the page could be specified as the third div (/div[3]) or with the div with the specific id "content" (/div[@id="content"]), as I stated in the question.

The content is not available only after login.

As for my HTML/XML/XPath syntax being horribly messed up, I believe that bears directly on the question.

Comment: I'm really getting another web page, than probably it's region-dependent or similar. I'm querying the page from Germany.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to **XPath 2.0** functions you can use intersect to select all elements between the two:

```
//hr[2]/following-sibling::node()
intersect
//hr[3]/preceding-sibling::node()
```

If you only have access to **XPath 1.0** functions, you can use this wonderful workaround to achieve the same result:

```
//hr[2]/following-sibling::node()[
count(.| //hr[3]/preceding-sibling::node()) 
= 
count(//hr[3]/preceding-sibling::node())
]
```

Comment: thank you for offer a concise & clear explanation that was compatible across versions.

Are there any other resources (other than the XPath Tutorial) that anyone can refer to me? Relatively new to this, but this language seems pretty clunky.